# How to set AppBar to autohide C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, appbar

I know that there is a way how to set my application desktop toolbar to autohide, but unfortunately I don't know how to use it properly. Can you someone give me an example, please? I'm programming `AppBar` in `C# WinForm`.

Thank you very much

There is a code, which I'm using for registering the `AppBar`.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct APPBARDATA
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public int uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    private enum ABMsg : int
    {
        ABM_NEW = 0,
        ABM_REMOVE,
        ABM_QUERYPOS,
        ABM_SETPOS,
        ABM_GETSTATE,
        ABM_GETTASKBARPOS,
        ABM_ACTIVATE,
        ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR,
        ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR,
        ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED,
        ABM_SETSTATE
    }

    private enum ABNotify : int
    {
        ABN_STATECHANGE = 0,
        ABN_POSCHANGED,
        ABN_FULLSCREENAPP,
        ABN_WINDOWARRANGE
    }

    private enum ABEdge : int
    {
        ABE_LEFT = 0,
        ABE_TOP,
        ABE_RIGHT,
        ABE_BOTTOM
    }

    private bool isBarRegistered = false;
    private int uCallBack;

    [DllImport("SHELL32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern uint SHAppBarMessage(int dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);

    [DllImport("USER32")]
    private static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int Index);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string msg);

    private void RegisterBar(bool dvojty)
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        if (!isBarRegistered)
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Strana.ToLower() == "ano")
            {
                this.Width = minSirka;
                this.Height = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location).WorkingArea.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Width = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location).WorkingArea.Width;
                this.Height = minVyska;
            }
            uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage");
            abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack;

            uint ret = SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_NEW, ref abd);
            isBarRegistered = true;

            ABSetPos(hrana);
        }
        else
        {
            toolBar = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE, ref abd);
            isBarRegistered = false;
            //this.TopMost = true;

            if (dvojty)
            {
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.Strana.ToLower() == "ano")
                {
                    this.Width = minSirka;
                    this.Height = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location).WorkingArea.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Width = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location).WorkingArea.Width;
                    this.Height = minVyska;
                }
                uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage");
                abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack;

                uint ret = SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_NEW, ref abd);
                isBarRegistered = true;

                ABSetPos(hrana);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ABSetPos(string edge)
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        //SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR, ref abd);
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;

        if (edge == "" || edge == "top")
        {
            abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP;
        }
        else if (edge == "right")
        {
            abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT;
        }
        else if (edge == "left")
        {
            abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT;
        }
        else if (edge == "bottom")
        {
            abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM;
        }
        else
        {
            abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP;
        }

        if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT || abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT)
        {
            abd.rc.top = 0;
            abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;

            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT)
            {
                abd.rc.left = 0;
                abd.rc.right = Size.Width;
                okraj = "left";
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
                okraj = "right";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.left = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Left;
            abd.rc.right = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Right;
            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP)
            {
                abd.rc.top = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Top;
                abd.rc.bottom = Size.Height;
                okraj = "top";  
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.bottom = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Bottom;
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
                okraj = "bottom";
            }
        }

        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref abd);

        switch (abd.uEdge)
        {
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT:
                abd.rc.right = abd.rc.left + Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT:
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP:
                abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + Size.Height;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM:
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
                break;
        }

        this.Top -= 1;
        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS, ref abd);
        MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, Size.Width, Size.Height, true);
        toolBar = new Rectangle(abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, Size.Width, Size.Height);
        left = this.Left;
        top = this.Top;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan for your respond. I mean regestered AppBar set as autohide, when I'm calling RegisterBar() method from the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many unsuccessful attempts, I decided to resolve the autohide in a different way. If I set appBar as an autohide, I will register it to the defined edge, but change its size from that edge to only 5 pixels, and all the controlls in it sets to visible = false and I set the appBar background to black color. From now on, I check the position of the mouse and as soon as the mouse moves to the appbar, appBar will once again grow to its original size - but NOT re-register, only edit size and set controlls to visible = true!! When mouse leav appBar, set size a visible of controlls back. It is very simple and after tests, both practical and trouble-free.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**

First, your `SHAppBarMessage()` declaration should be returning `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("SHELL32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr SHAppBarMessage(int dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);
```

Then, as per the documentation for [ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787945(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787957(v=vs.85).aspx), there can only be one AppBar with AutoHide per edge of the screen.  So after filling out your APPBARDATA structure in your ABSetPos() method (specifying what edge you are going to use), you can query the system to see if there is already an auto-hiding bar on that edge.  If none is returned, then you can register your appbar...something like:

```
IntPtr curAutoHide = SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, ref abd);
if (curAutoHide.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) // if there is no current appbar with autohide set for that edge...
{
    abd.lParam = new IntPtr(1); // true
    SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR, ref abd);
}
```

Comment: Hi, firstly really thank you for your respond. I tryed your example, but it does not work. It seems like auto-hide is for my appbar is true (after execute your code). but nothing happened. Because when I run my appBar curAutoHide is 0, so ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR is executed, but when app still running and I unregister and register appbar again, curAutoHide is not 0. So I'm thinking that registering autohide is OK, but it seems like there is another problem.